# prove that there is at least one pentagon where you cannot get a triangle from any diagonals (a pentagon may not be convex)

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, examples-counterexamples

find a pentagon where you cannot get a triangle from any diagonals (a pentagon may not be convex)
(a triangle is not in a pentagon; it is obtained with the help of diagonals; if there are any three diagonals of length which make it possible to form a triangle from these three diagonals, then that pentagon already considered unnecessary to us)
I don't know how to find that pentagon.
I just know that if it's convex, then there always is such a triangle of diagonals.
So I have to look for a not convex pentagon.

[image: https://photos.app.goo.gl/Pboq7NVAcxDnpVBv9]

Comment: One would have to know what "get a triangle from any diagonals" means.

Comment: And do you only allow simple pentagons (without overlapping of the sides)?

Comment: rather get a triangle from some 3 diagonals of this pentagon.  and besides, any pentagons are  resolved

Comment: I suppose the triangle has to be contained in the pentagon, otherwise every three points of the pentagon provides a triangle.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by your question, but if you want a pentagon whose five diagonals make no triangles I can think of an example - of course any three diagonals will make a triangle if you extend them (except in the special case of parallel diagonals). So I guess you are working within the convex hull defined by the five vertices.

Comment: a triangle is not in a pentagon; it is obtained with the help of diagonals; if there are any three diagonals of length which make it possible to form a triangle from these three diagonals, then that pentagon already considered unnecessary to us

Comment: A picture would be helpful to define what you mean with 'forming' a triangle. And what is a diagonal for you; i.e. can a diagonal be outside the pentagon?

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/Pboq7NVAcxDnpVBv9

Comment: The OP means that no three diagonals have lengths that can be used to construct a triangle. (It's there in the question, but not so easy too interpret.)

Comment: How do you prove that such a pentagon cannot be convex?

Comment: I examined the largest diagonal and proved that there are always two more for this diagonal, the sum of which is greater than this diagonal https://photos.app.goo.gl/15f7kWQsH6BpJfxw6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: counter-example]
You can make your pentagons such that there are only 2 diagonals, then of course, no triangle is possible. I also provided an example of a pentagon with three diagonals.

---

When you also allow outer diagonals, then the diagonals form a loop. By deforming the loop you also get a pentagon. So the question becomes can we find a pentagon such that the lengths of the sides never form a triangle, and this pentagon are the diagonals from a different pentagon. We can find such lengths: $1$, $2$, $3$, $5$, $8$ (note that this is part of the Fibonacci sequence)
Below is such a pentagon (red are the diagonals) The lengths of $AB$, $BC$, $CD$, $DE$, and $EA$ are respectively $8$, $5$, $3$, $2$, and $1$.
[image: counter-example-with-outer-diagonals]

Comment: But can not the diagonals be outside the polygon?        If they can't, we are done.

Comment: @DeltaAccount, for the purposes of this question, I think we must assume that the diagonals can lie outside the pentagon. Otherwise it's too easy, as Simon shows.

Comment: I updated the answer also for outside lying diagonals.